# expanding thumbnail to larger size image and the reverse

Tags: jquery

I have some thumbnails on an "About Us" page which I would like to expand in size when they are clicked and the reverse, when clicked, the enlarged image reverts to the thumbnail. I've checked SO and elsewhere but I've not been able to find any code that does this. I would prefer a solution using jquery as I have some (limited) experience with it. Any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You wont find anything if you dont know what are you looking for. This is to make div bigger on its click, you could use similar type of logic towards your image, if its div, then you could change its id and thats all.

```js
$('#about_us').on('click', function() {
 if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
   $(this).css({'width': '50px', 'height': '50px'});
   $(this).removeClass('active');
  } else {
 $(this).css({'width': '150px', 'height': '150px'});
   $(this).addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
#about_us {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px; background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='about_us'>
</div>
```

You could use different approach and add classes with its parameters of height, or you could play with its css directly and add class like hare - active, so you would know its clicked.